# is it better to use git revert for solving a bug or just make a branch in buggy commit and then merge it?

Tags: git

I'm kind of new with git and I'm confused with the `git revert` concept... for instance if I have a bug in `master~5`, isn't that better to switch to `master~5`, diverge a branch like `test` from it and fix the bug then merge the latest commit in the `test` branch to the `master` than just      `git revert` from `master`, because in `git revert` case it doesn't fix the bug and just remove the effect of buggy commit and I have to deal with missing file and the issues they can make in the reverted commit ... so I'm wondering which approach is better or where in my logic I'm wrong?

Comment: Though it's kind of implied (and also addressed in the accepted answer), the two things you are comparing in your question aren't the same. (One is fixing the bug, the other is reverting the bug without fixing it.) I feel like the comparison might be better (and more interesting) if you explicitly asked about reverting and then fixing, compared to just fixing like you proposed...

Comment: I'm comparing a problem with two approaches...and I'm looking to pick the best approach among these two... this question is not just about `git revert`@TTT

Comment: Possibly you misunderstood my comment? I'm simply saying that the two things you are comparing have different end states (one fixes the problem and one doesn't). I think it would be a little clearer if both things fixed the problem (since I assume that's the ultimate goal).

Comment: Actually... I just realized the original version of the question before the edit had it the way I'm proposing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do.  Options include:

- quick fix to previous state. This is often a case where a fix was applied but it broke the system in other ways.  The primary objective is just to remove the offending code and in git that means a revert.
- immediate fix to resolve the issue.  This is what you would like to do.  You can do it.  The downsides are that your fix may or may not work and may or may not affect other parts of the application.

Generally I prefer to do small atomic operations so I do

- git revert
- new branch
- create a fix
- test it well
- merge to master.

Essentially the process for fixing a break should be the same as the process for adding or changing code.  Having special procedures that are different is not advisable in my experience.

Comment: so you mean when I have a bug in a certain commit, it is better first to revert it to undo the effect of the buggy commit then create a branch to fix the missing particle due to undoing the buggy commit then I merge it to my main branch(i.e master)? am I correct?

Comment: @alex_121 yes  It avoids the issue when a fix to a fix doesn't work and then you are further away from the code that originally worked.  As with most things, breaking it down into small steps and changes is the safest thing to do.

Comment: and for anyone unfamiliar with "revert" what it does it post changes to the code that will take it back to a previous state. e.g. if a line was added it will now be removed, etc.  In common language you are "removing the commit" but in actually practice you are posting _another_ commit that has the effect of reversing the first commit.  Luckily git handles all this if you know the process and commandfs and steps to use

Comment: tnx man @MichaelDurrant